# Expressing negativity in predicate logic

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

For context:

> Consider the predicate logic  language with the natural numbers {0, 1,
>   2, 3, . . .} as  constants; the predicates < (x < y means x is smaller
>   than y); = (x = y means x is equal to y)....

Apologies for this very basic question, but I'm slightly confused. For this formula:

$∀x(x≠0 → 0<x)$

≠ doesn't exist in our language which only includes {¬,→,∧,∨,∀,∃}.

So should it be expressed like: $∀x(x=¬0 → 0<x)$ or as $∀x(x¬=0 → 0<x)$

Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Note that your language doesn't include $<$ either.

Comment: Apologies, that was an extract from a question where they've specified that < is a predicate. I shall edit the post to include that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the $\neq$ predicate is considered to be an abbreviation: "$t\neq u$" is simply a space-saving (and, arguably, more readable) way to write $\neg(t=u)$.

Neither "$t=\neg u$" nor "$t \mathrel{{\neg}{=}} u$" are well-formed, though: The $\neg$ symbol must always apply to a complete formula.

In most formal developments, $\neg(t=u)$ is again an abbreviation of something like $\neg(p_0^2(t,u))$, where $p_0^2$ is the predicate letter one has chosen to use for equality -- but that's a different story.

Comment: Ah many thanks, that makes sense